# Find the relation between sides of a triangle

Tags: geometry

If $m$ is the intersection of triangle's medians that find the relation of sides so that angles $BCM$ and $ABM$ are equal.

I tried both $\sin$ and $\cos$ law because we had two angles equal also I tried to construct the angle another where so they built a cyclic quadrilateral but non of them worked.So what should I do?

Comment: Are A, B, and C vertices of the triangle?  Is the lower case m the same as the upper case M?  Please actually *state* these assumptions.

Comment: @fleablood Yes to all of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $AB=c$, $AC=b$, $BC=a$ and $m_b$, $m_c$ be medians of the triangle to $AC$ and $AB$ respectively.

Thus, $m_b=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2a^2+2c^2-b^2}$ and $m_c=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2-c^2}$ and by law of cosines we obtain:
$$\frac{\frac{1}{4}(2a^2+2c^2-b^2)+c^2-\frac{1}{4}b^2}{\sqrt{2a^2+2c^2-b^2}c}=\frac{\frac{1}{4}(2a^2+2b^2-c^2)+a^2-\frac{c^2}{4}}{\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2-c^2}a}$$  or
$$\frac{a^2+3c^2-b^2}{c\sqrt{2a^2+2c^2-b^2}}=\frac{b^2+3a^2-c^2}{a\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2-c^2}},$$
which after squaring of the both sides gives:
$$(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a+c-b)(b+c-a)(2a^2+c^2)(a^2+b^2-2c^2)=0,$$
which gives $a^2+b^2=2c^2$. It's all.

Comment: It seems to be true I'll read it tomorrow then accept it But Would you add a picture for make it easy understandable please.

Comment: Also you considered angles equal and then solved it but the question wants the reverse of it can we get back using the answer?

Comment: @Taha Akbari I don't know to draw. But you can draw medians $CM$ and $BK$ and write low of cosines for $\Delta ABK$ and $\Delta CBM$. By  the way, I proved that the statement about equality our angles is equivalent to $a^2+b^2=2c^2$.

Comment: What about my second comment?

Comment: @Taha Akbari Because for angles $\cos\alpha=\cos\beta\Leftrightarrow\alpha=\beta$